# Postgres foreign key issue in Spring Boot JPA repositories

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data

I'm trying to create a simple "OneToMany" relationship between two tables.
A Person can have multiple Associations
A Person'a name is unique so I am using this for my foreign key.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "persons", uniqueConstraints=  @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name"}))
    public class Person
    {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        private String name;

        @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
        @OneToMany(targetEntity=Association.class, mappedBy="nameFrom")
        private List<Association> associations;

       ...getters/setters and constructors...
    }

@Entity
@Table(name = "association")
public class Association
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String nameFrom;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="name")
    public String getNameFrom() {
        return nameFrom;
    }
    ...getters/setters and constructors...
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: foreign key constraint "fk72o5vm9iwse7jgxu2cyg552uq" cannot be implemented
  Detail: Key columns "name_from" and "id" are of incompatible types: character varying and bigint.
```

I tried setting the @Id annotation on the name field of the Person class but it made no difference.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Where's the column named `alias`? It's also not a good idea to use strings or other such things as foreign keys. Even if you currently think that names are unique.

Comment: oh, sorry, wrong copy-paste. I'll update the exception

Comment: You should also choose whether you annotate the columns or the methods. Mixing them up like that causes confusion.

Comment: Foreign keys reference the primary key of another table. Your both entities have a `Long id` as the PK (which is good). You can have a `@ManyToOne` association to a `Person` if you want, but currently your whole `nameFrom` attribute doesn't make any sense. It certainly doesn't need any join columns or ManyToOne annotations.

Comment: Try adding the `referencedColumnName` in the `@JoinColumn` of Association

Comment: Do you want to use `name` as the primary key, or do you want for some reason to have both nice numeric primary keys as well as an additional "pseudo-PK" as you seem to be doing? You're talking about a "simple relationship", but you've managed to write your code in the most complex fashion. The `@ManyToOne` should also be associated to a `Person` field, not your `String nameFrom`.

Comment: I ended up using "name" as my PK in my Person class. 
Thank you for your answers

Comment: please add the sql table structure to detect the exact error. Thank You :)